# complex mongodb query for calculating average time difference

Tags: python, mongodb, average

I have mongo documents in my collection. They look something like this:

```
{
 "created_at": 1427815513.97 (String)
 "results": {
       "value": "whatever",
       "created_at": 1427815613.97 (String) 
   } 
}
```

I can see when this item was created and when it's results were created so I can calculate the `time difference between start and end`

My question is how Do I get the **average time difference** for all my documents?

assumptions: not all my docs have `created_at` fields or `results` fields so the average calculate is only valid for those who has these fields.

Thanks.

Comment: you should store `created_at` as integer instead of string, so you could achive this in a single query using the aggregation framework.Otherwise you'll need to do this directly in python...

Comment: isn't it possible to do it in the mongo js console?